# Filtering Nulls from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005.

Data is in 2 separate tables and I have only been given write permissions.

Data looks like:

```
DateTime1  |  DateTime2
-----------------------
2012-06-01 | 2012-06-01
2012-06-02 | 2012-06-02
2012-06-04 | 2012-06-05
2012-06-02 | NULL
NULL       | 2012-06-05
2012-06-04 | 2012-06-05
NULL       | NULL
```

What I am trying to do is be able to count values in which DateTime1 and DateTime2 contain values, DateTime1 contains a date and DateTime2 is NULL, DateTime1 is NULL and DateTime2 contains values.

Overall Im trying to avoid DateTime1 being Null and DateTime2 being null.

My ***where*** statement looks like this:

```
Where (DateTime1 is not null or DateTime2 is not null)
```

The only problem is it is still showing where both are null values. Anyone know why this might be happening or how to solve it?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Full Query as requested by @Lamak

```
;With [CTE] As (
Select
    TH.ID
    ,AMT
    ,Reason
    ,EffDate
    ,DateReq
    ,CS_ID
    ,ROW_NUMBER()
        Over (Partition By ID Order By [pthPrimeKey] Desc) as [RN]
From
    DateTime1Table as [MC] (nolock)
    Left Join History as [TH] (nolock) on [TH].[ID] = [MC].[ID]
    Left Join Trans as [SUB] (nolock) on [SUB].TransactionReasonCode = [TH].Reason
    Left Join Renew as [RM] (nolock) on [MC].ID = [RM].ID
Where 
    ([MC].[DateTime1] is not null or [RM].[DateTime2] is not null)
    And [PostingDate] = DATEADD(dd, datediff(dd, 1, GetDate()),0)
)
SELECT 
[ID]
,[AMT] as [Earned]
,[Reason] as [Reason]
,[EffDate] as [Eff]
,[DateReq] as [Date_Cancel_Req]
,[pthUserId_Number] as [CSR]
FROM [CTE]
Where RN <= 1
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` is fine, the problem must be something else. Are you sure that the values are actually `NULL`?, Are those columns of datat type `DATETIME`?, because it can be that you have the string `'NULL'` there

Comment: @GSerg - Why?, s/he only needs to filter results where both columns are `NULL`, and thats what the `WHERE` is doing

Comment: @Lamak The columns are DateTime and its not a string NULL value it is a true NULL value.

Comment: @Lamak Because I misunderstood what should be selected, as did everyone else who posted answers so far.

Comment: @GSerg - It seems so. Anyway, I'm quite intrigued as to why op is having this problem. Brad, can you post your whole query?, are you using a view?

Comment: Greg: can you post a) your DDL and b) your DML (as @Lamak requested). Preferably in a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: @Lamak I can post the entire query however there are many other tables which are being joined as well that have no impact.. Stand By..

Comment: @Brad ... on the most basic level, the `WHERE` approach works. https://gist.github.com/2919639

Comment: How will you ever have a `ROW_NUMBER()` of less than 1? (Hint: you won't!)

Comment: Can you properly prefix all of your columns so we know which table each column comes from?

Comment: Your existing where clause seems to work. Can you please simplify this query so that all of the other joins and CTEs and filters are not present? My suspicion is that rows are getting erroneously excluded due to other parts of the query other than that specific where clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will allow rows to be included if

- only DateTime1 has a value
- only DateTime2 has a value
- both have values

It will exclude rows where both values are NULL. Is that what you're after? (I tried to follow the conversations but got lost, and wish you'd have a simpler repro with sample data - I think the CTE and all the other joins and logic really take away from the actual problem you're having.)

```
WHERE COALESCE([MC].[DateTime1], [RM].[DateTime2]) IS NOT NULL
```

However, since you're performing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, this may belong in the `ON` clause for `[RM]` instead of `WHERE`. Otherwise you won't know if a row is excluded because the value in a matching row was NULL, or because there was no matching row. And maybe that's ok, just thought I would mention it.

**EDIT**

Of course, that clause provides the exact same results as ...

```
WHERE ([MC].[DateTime1] is not null or [RM].[DateTime2] is not null)
```

Want proof?

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(id INT, DateTime1 DATETIME);
DECLARE @b TABLE(id INT, DateTime2 DATETIME);

INSERT @a SELECT 1, '20120602' ; INSERT @b SELECT 1, NULL;
INSERT @a SELECT 2, NULL       ; INSERT @b SELECT 2, '20120605';
INSERT @a SELECT 3, '20120604' ; INSERT @b SELECT 3, '20120605';
INSERT @a SELECT 4, NULL       ; INSERT @b SELECT 4, NULL;
INSERT @a SELECT 5, '20120602' ; INSERT @b SELECT 9, NULL;
INSERT @a SELECT 6, NULL       ; INSERT @b SELECT 10, '20120605';
INSERT @a SELECT 7, '20120604' ; INSERT @b SELECT 11, '20120605';
INSERT @a SELECT 8, NULL       ; INSERT @b SELECT 12, NULL;

SELECT * FROM @a AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN @b AS b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE COALESCE(a.DateTime1, b.DateTime2) IS NOT NULL;

SELECT * FROM @a AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN @b AS b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.DateTime1 IS NOT NULL OR b.DateTime2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Both queries yield:

```
id DateTime1  id   DateTime2
-- ---------- ---- ----------
1  2012-06-02 1    NULL       -- because left is not null
2  NULL       2    2012-06-05 -- because right is not null
3  2012-06-04 3    2012-06-05 -- because neither is null
5  2012-06-02 NULL NULL       -- because of no match
7  2012-06-04 NULL NULL       -- because of no match
```

So as I suggested in the comment, if you're not seeing the rows you expect, you need to look at other parts of the query. If you provide sample data and desired results, we can try to help you narrow that down. As it is, I don't think we know enough about your schema and data to determine where the problem is.

Comment: Im not quite sure why based off the test data why it works, but coalesce did the trick. Thank You!